# Native (Windows/Linux) support with API

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Are there any plans for the API  to support native OS apps on these platforms? It would be great to be able to embed Chromecast support into for example - an application like XBMC.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle, there is currently no immediate plans to provide native support. As a side note, Chrome SDK provides support on those platforms.

Comment: Chrome SDK does not provide support on those platforms, it provides support on Chrome. The difference between what Chrome offers and what a native library offers is massive and completely non-comparable.